# How to dynamically add textbox on button click in Vue Js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an object with key-value pair which I have used to generate textboxes using key as the label and value as the textbox value using the v-for loop. I want to add a new textbox on add button click. Here's the code.

```html
<CRow>
  <CCol sm="6">
    <CDropdown toggler-text="My Test">
      <CDropdownHeader>--Select--</CDropdownHeader>
      <CDropdownItem
        v-for="(value, key) in keys_with_empty_value"
        :key="key"
        >{{ key }}</CDropdownItem
      >
    </CDropdown>
  </CCol>
  <CCol sm="6">
    <CButton :color="'info'" @click="addtextbox"> Add </CButton>
  </CCol>
</CRow>
<CRow>
  <CCol
    sm="6"
    v-for="(value, key, index) in keys_with_not_empty_value"
    :key="key"
  >
    <CInput :label="key" type="text" v-model="keys_with_not_empty_value[key]" />
  </CCol>
</CRow>
```

and my click event is :

```js
    methods:{
    addtextbox() {
          this.keys_with_not_empty_value.system_dummy_data = "";
        },
    }
```

I am adding new key in my object which I used in v-for and generated other textboxes. To my understanding to vue-js if I change any data in vue script part it should reflect on HTML part. but my v-for loop is not updating and I am not able to see new textbox for the newly added key.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work in this [demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-new-obj-key-in-v-for?file=src/App.vue), but it only adds *one* new textbox because `addtextbox` only inserts a specific key (instead of a new unique key).

However, the component names suggest you're using [Core UI](https://coreui.io/vue/), which currently (v3.1.4) only works with Vue 2. In Vue 2, newly added object keys are [not automatically detected](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects), so you would need to use [`vm.$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) to insert the new key:

```js
export default {
  methods:{
    addtextbox() {
      //this.keys_with_not_empty_value.system_dummy_data = "";
      this.$set(keys_with_not_empty_value, "system_dummy_data", "");
    },
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-new-obj-key-in-v-for-34vzb?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: I got your point... but somehow my HTML doesn't get reflected but when I check it on console the key is already added in object

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction in Codesandbox, Codepen, stackblitz, etc?